# Cleartool command for finding a particular activity across streams

Tags: clearcase

I know an activity name. But I don't know in which stream it is available. Is there a `cleartool` command to find the stream details?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at **[`fmt_ccase`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm)** format option (applicable to the `cleartool describe` command for instance).

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%[stream]Xp" activity:myActivity@\myPVob
```

The man page mentions:

```
%[stream]Xp
```

- applies to:
  Activity
- Description:
  The stream that contains the activity